# what is the difference between Linux drivers and Android driver

Tags: android, linux, device-driver

As android kernel is a hacked version of linux kernel..

So the way we write drivers for linux would that work in android or some modifications are to be done .?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some API differences between Android and Linux kernel drivers code, any drivers written for Android hardware platforms can not get merged into the main kernel tree because they have dependencies on code that only lives in Google's kernel tree, causing it to fail to build in the kernel.org tree.

["Android and Linux are growing back together"](https://www.computerworld.com/article/2468908/android-and-linux-are-growing-back-together.html) would give you more insight to your question.

Comment: tl;dr: Most drivers are exactly the same under Linux and Android (i.e. filesystems, USB devices, etc). Drivers that deal with power management or low-level graphics will have problems because of the slightly different API.

Comment: I am interested in the post from the link? Is it still available somewhere? ( I am aware that is probably not up to date due to its age)

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 I understand that several years have passed since your message, but anyway I've updated the broken link.